# /usr/bin/python: No module named pip under mac / install python package in mac

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to use python with visual code under mac computer

I have this error message :

```
/usr/bin/python -m pip install pylint
user:~ user$ /usr/bin/python -m pip install pylint
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
```

I have find some help and try this :

```
user:~ user$ easy_install pip
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-19813.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

I don't uderstand why I have this :

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-19813.pth'
```

as I have put this line in my bash_profile

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

How can I install library and use python with my mac ? (Usually I use Linux system in my work place but now I am on my personal computer...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to run your `easy_install` command with sudo privileges if you want to write to `/Library`

Try running the following command:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

and then enter your password

Answer (score 5):

Download get-pip.py from below link
[get-pip.py](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwim0YCdzIbXAhUBjLwKHW5IASQQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbootstrap.pypa.io%2Fget-pip.py&usg=AOvVaw0zKVO_zW0nkF7s0zdjWFNj)

And download pip as

```
python get-pip.py
```

After that you can install modules using `pip install modulename`

Comment: I have this error : /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory . /MacOS/Python is not a directory so I can't move pip.py on it..

Comment: Where did you place get-pip.py ? can you give full path of get-pip.py ?also make sure you have proper permissions to access that file

Comment: I put it in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/‌​Python.app/Contents/‌​MacOS/ ; but the previous solution has worked with sudo easy_install . Thank you for you help

Comment: Good to know :-)